# How to select 2 fields if they meet requirements & length in awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to select 2 fields and out put them to a file:

field$1 I want to select all if it = @ symbol (for email)

field$2 I want to select if it = certain character length ie. 40.
only output if both requirements are met, how to do this in awk or sed?

I was using this:

```
awk -F: '/\@/ {print $1 ":" $2 }' test.txt > file_output.txt
```

however the @ is for both $1 and $2 which is not what i want.
Thanks,

Edit: here is an example (in bold)

**email@some.com:123456789123456789123456789**:blah:blah:blah

ignore:1234@56789

output needed:
email@some.com:123456789123456789123456789

Comment: Please post some example data with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this;

```
  awk -F: '{if ($1 ~ /\@/ && length($2) == 40) print $1 ":" $2  }' test.txt > file_output.txt
```

Test;

sample file

```
$ cat t
user@host1:0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
user@host2:0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
userhost3:0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
user@host4:012345677
```

awk output;

```
$ awk -F: '{if ($1 ~ /\@/ && length($2) == 40) print $0 }' t
user@host1:0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
user@host2:0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

Comment: Thanks! the solution is elegant :)